# Refactoring filenames in DartPolymer project errors by looking at old filenames

Tags: intellij-idea, dart

I am working in IntelliJIdea and working on a PolymerDart webapp.  I am in the process of a file name refactor across the board, but when I try to serve, all pointers are looking to old filenames.

I tried to repair cache, hoping that it would pick up the new information, but that wasn't working.  Another teammate is now having the same issue.  Is there something we are forgetting to do?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "all pointers are looking to old filenames". You renamed the files but imports are pointing to old files? What Dart version are you using?. I'm not sure if this was ever worked completely. If you have a reproducible case please report a bug in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com

Comment: Ok.  sounds good.  Yeah, it seems like it is resolved when i restart the application so i think it is a jetbrains thing and not a dart thing.

Comment: Might be a DartAnalyzer problem if restarting fixes it. DartAnalyzer is started by IntelliJ/WebStorm automatically. WebStorm/IntelliJ just delegates many tasks  to it like syntax highlighting, errors, warnings, autocompletion and quick-fixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up just closing IntelliJIdea and restarting it. That seems to do to the trick.